# How to move a rectangle to x, y coordinates in JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, path

I'm looking for "how to move my bullet to x,y coords", but i haven't find any help or usefull topics.. :|

Well, there is my code :

```
GoToMouse()
{
    this.goX = mouse.x;
    this.goY = mouse.y;

    this.dx = this.goX;
    this.dy = this.goY;


}

UpdatePosition()
{
    this.x += this.dx / 1000;
    this.y += this.dy / 1000;
}
```

Of course, every 60ms, i draw the rect !

So, the code work, when the rect start from 0,0
But, when the bullet start from, for exemple, 10,10 it's less accuary, and bigger is the start point lower is the bullet accuary :|

Thanks ! :)

Comment: There's a whole topic on ["Animation"](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/4822/animation#t=201608262110390496573) in the new Stackoverflow Docs. You can see by example how to animation your drawings (eg bullets) across the screen.

Comment: Hi, I have read this but i haven't find the awnser :/,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [animation tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/). You can see by example how to animate your drawings (eg bullets) across the screen.

**Use vectors to calculate incremental [x,y] from [startX,startY] to [endX,endY]**

```
// dx is the total distance to move in the X direction
var dx = endX - startX;

// dy is the total distance to move in the Y direction
var dy = endY - startY;

// use a pct (percentage) to travel the total distances
// start at 0% which == the starting point
// end at 100% which == then ending point
var pct=0;  

// use dx & dy to calculate where the current [x,y] is at a given pct
var x = startX + dx * pct/100;
var y = startY + dx * pct/100;
```

**Example code and a demo to get you started:**

```js
// canvas vars
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

// animating vars
var pct=101;
var startX,startY,endX,endY,dx,dy;

// canvas styles
ctx.strokeStyle='skyblue';
ctx.fillStyle='blue';

// start animation loop running
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

// listen for mouse events
window.onmousedown=(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
window.onmouseup=(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});

// constantly running loop
// will animate bullet 
function animate(time){
    // return if there's no bullet to animate
    if(++pct>100){requestAnimationFrame(animate);return;}
    // update
    x=startX+dx*pct/100;
    y=startY+dy*pct/100;
    // draw
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
    ctx.lineTo(endX,endY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,5,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill()
    // request another animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // save ending position
  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // set flag
  pct=101;
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // save ending position and vector
  endX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  endY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  dx=endX-startX;
  dy=endY-startY;
  // set pct=0 to start animating
  pct=0;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<h4>Drag the mouse<br>Mousedown sets starting position,<br>Mouseup sets ending position and animates.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```