# Preventing elements from jumping abruptly in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, requestanimationframe

This is my pseudocode:

```
when move button is pressed:
    currentCirclePos = circleX;
    moveTimer = setInterval(move, 10);
```

My move function looks like this:

```
var move = function() {
    circleX += move a bit;
};
```

In some cases, the element does not move at all. For those situations, I have the following code :

```
while(Math.abs(circleX - currentCirclePos) < some distance away){
    drawCircle(circleX, circleY);
    circleX += gradual shift;
}
```

This does not change the position of my circle gradually but draws it abruptly `some distance away`. I don't understand why is that happening. Could anyone help me debug the issue? Let me know if I need to post more code.

This is my `requestAnimationFrame` code:

```
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(){ 
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.rect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fill();
    drawCircle(circleX, circleY);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

UPDATE : The while loop was not inside the animation function but now it is. However, it did not make any difference at all.

Comment: That `while` loop looks like it could be a "jumping" villain, but it's hard to tell without more code. Are you trying to move your circle to a certain location over a set duration? If yes, then use the timestamp that's automatically fed into the requestAnimationFrame callback to calculate elapsed time. Move your circle from start to destination based on the percentage of time elapsed in the duration: `circleX = startingCircleX + (endingCircleX-startingCircleX) * elapsedTime/totalTimeDuration`

Comment: @markE Yeah, I also think that the jumping is due to the while loop but I added the draw circle code inside to make sure that it redraws it after every increment in `circleX`. I can move the element to desired location using the `while` loop above. My problem is that the circle is drawn directly at point B instead of moving gradually from point A towards point B.

Comment: Here's a [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172583/how-to-move-a-rectangle-to-x-y-coordinates-in-js/39193754#39193754) showing how to use the timestamp to move from A to B over a time duration D.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that You're using `setInterval` instead of [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) - it's more reliable way to do this kind of operations on canvas.

Please check [this tutorial](http://nokarma.org/2011/02/02/javascript-game-development-the-game-loop/index.html) - author solves this problem pretty straightforward on example.

Comment: Additionally it's important to do movement based on time passed and not say "Increase X by 10px every frame". Because that will have different results on slow and fast devices.

Comment: Actually, I am using requestAnimationFrame. Let me add more code. :)

Comment: My animation is always smooth. It changes abruptly only in edge cases where the minimum distance moved is less than the threshold value and I increase it using a while loop.